# Scala Arraylist with another class

Tags: scala, arraylist

Hi guys i'm a beginner and i have a problem with this code is. I am trying to create an arraylist but it can only use the default class Members

The problem lies in here   var memberList : ArrayList[Members] with an error message of :
Error:(13, 30) not found: type Members
var memberList : ArrayList[Members]

Does anyone know a workaround with it?

The sample code is below.

```
import java.util.{ArrayList}

abstract class Groups(){
  val groupName: String
  val groupType: String
  var memberList : ArrayList[Members]

  def addMember(enter: String): Unit = {
    memberList.add(enter)
  }

  def deleteMember(del: String): Any = {
    memberList.remove(del)
  }
}



class Members(var name: String, var permission: String){
}
```

Comment: The error I see is that you try to `.add`/`.remove` `String` while `memberList` is an `ArrayList` of `Members`. Also `var` is not needed there unless you want to be able to replace whole `ArrayList[Members]` instance from the outside.

Comment: i see your insight gave me guidance. The reason for var is i want to change elements of the group members. 

If i change 
  def addMember(enter: String): Unit  to  def addMember(enter: Members) it would work as intended. right?

And i solved my original question by shifting class Members to be above abstract class Groups and it solved everything.

Comment: Why are you using a **Java** array list on **Scala**? When we have a bunch of useful collections.

Comment: @PotatoSingh Yes, if you change the method signatures to take in parameters of type `Members`, it would work. Also, you don't need `var` to change the elements. Even with `val`, it'll work, because the add and remove methods aren't pure and change your ArrayList internally.